Is it possible to dual boot Asahi distros on an Apple Silicon MacBook Pro?
I have a M1 MacBook Pro 1TB triple booting into macOS Sonoma, macOS Sequoia (beta), and Asahi Linux.
When I installed Asahi Linux, I resized the APFS partition to leave 100GB available and used 50GB for Asahi Linux.
I want to install Asahi Ubuntu to the 50GB of free space and just want to make sure there aren’t any gotchas I should be aware of before I start as I’m surprised this is not in the Asahi FAQ.
Has anyone gotten this working and have you run into any issues running the default Asahi Ubuntu installer on top of your macOS/Asahi install or run into any issues with this type of multi-boot setup?
curl -sL https://ubuntuasahi.org/install | sh

Or any of the other alternative distros?

https://github.com/AsahiLinux/docs/wiki/SW%3AAlternative-Distros

